# Cannot install fonts with Powershell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

On my work computer, I don't have admin privileges.

Installing new fonts cannot be done "the easy way".

At the time I was using Windows 7, I managed to run a PowerShell script that was launched at session startup and that installed the fonts from a given folder.

Here is the code I used:

```
add-type -name Session -namespace "" -member @"
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern int AddFontResource(string filePath);
"@

$FontFolder = "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts"

$null = foreach($font in Get-ChildItem -Path $FontFolder -Recurse -Include *.ttf, *.otg, *.otf) {
    Write-Host "Installing : $($font.FullName)"
    $result = [Session]::AddFontResource($font.FullName)
    Write-Host "Installed $($result) fonts"
}
```

Now that I have switched to Windows 10, I thought I could go back to installing fonts "the easy way", as it is supposed to be possible to install fonts for your user without admin privileges.

This however still does not work: there is a popup window saying that "The requested file  is not a valid font file". [One solution is apparently to start the Windows firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/957907/unable-to-install-fonts-on-windows-10), <s>which of course is not allowed by my administrator...</s> but it is already running (see Edit below)

Back to the PowerShell then. The script unfortunately does not work anymore and does not provide any interesting pointers to where the problem comes from:

```
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\zilla-slab\ZillaSlab-SemiBold.otf
Installed 0 fonts
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\zilla-slab\ZillaSlab-SemiBoldItalic.otf
Installed 0 fonts
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\zilla-slab\ZillaSlabHighlight-Bold.otf
Installed 0 fonts
```

I tried using a try catch, but still have no identified error:

```
add-type -name Session -namespace "" -member @"
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern int AddFontResource(string filePath);
"@

$FontFolder = "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts"

$null = foreach($font in Get-ChildItem -Path $FontFolder -Recurse -Include *.ttf, *.otg, *.otf) {
    try {
        Write-Host "Installing : $($font.FullName)"
        $result = [Session]::AddFontResource($font.FullName)
        Write-Host $result
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "An error occured installing $($font)"
        Write-Host "$($error)"
        Write-Host "$($error[0].ToString())"
        Write-Host ""
        1
    }   
}
```

And the resulting output

```
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\zilla-slab\ZillaSlabHighlight-Bold.otf
0
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\zilla-slab\ZillaSlabHighlight-Regular.otf
0
Installing : C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Fonts\ZillaSlab-Light.otf
0
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

Regarding the status of the security applications, here is the McAfee status:

```
McAfee Data Exchange Layer OK 
McAfee DLP Endpoint OK 
Programme de mise à jour McAfee OK 
McAfee Endpoint Security OK
```

"Programme de mise à jour" means "update program" in French.

I also checked the list of running services :

- mpssvc service (Windows defender firewall) is running
- mfefire (McAfee Firewall core service) is not running

**Edit2:**

My last attempt is the following:

- I copied the font file manually to the $($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\ folder
- Using regedit, I added the entry as shown below

[image]

I restarted. Still no Bebas font in WordPad or Publisher

Comment: Something you said about starting the firewall caught my interest.  Is the firewall service running with the firewall profiles disabled?  Or is the firewall service itself disabled?  The firewall service itself should not be disabled.  There are ancillary functions it performs relating to security and cryptography that break when its disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the post. The firewall service is enabled. I don't know how to check the firewall profiles.

Comment: When you say "the easy way", do you mean right-clicking the font file and choosing the "Install" option from the context-sensitive menu? It works fine here with your ZillaSlab example font for a non-admin user.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by "the easy way". On my computer, it does not work: I have a popup saying "The requested file is not a valid font file". I have checked with multiple font files, downloaded them again and again, from different sources. I always have the popup

Comment: Very strange. Any clues in the Windows Event log?

Comment: Not where I looked at least

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it with a com object.  This works for me as non-admin based on [Install fonts without administrative privileges](https://onpremisys.nl/2019/07/10/install-fonts-without-administrative-privileges).  I can see the fonts installed to "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts" in the Fonts area under Settings.  I have Windows 10 20H2 (it should work in 1803 or higher).  I also see the fonts installed in Wordpad.

```
$Destination = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace(20)

$TempFolder = "$($env:windir)\Temp\Fonts\"

New-Item -Path $TempFolder -Type Directory -Force | Out-Null

Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\fonts\* -Include '*.ttf','*.ttc','*.otf' | 
  ForEach {
    If (-not(Test-Path "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\$($_.Name)")) {

        $Font = "$($env:windir)\Temp\Fonts\$($_.Name)"

        Copy-Item  $($_.FullName) -Destination $TempFolder
        
        $Destination.CopyHere($Font)

        Remove-Item $Font -Force

    } else { "font $($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\$($_.Name) already installed" }

}
```

Example REG_SZ registry entry:

```
dir 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts*' | ft -a


    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion


Name  Property
----  --------
Fonts Nunito Black (TrueType) : C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\Nunito-Black.ttf
```

Comment: This link says newer versions of windows 10 can do it without being admin:  https://onpremisys.nl/2019/07/10/install-fonts-without-administrative-privileges

Comment: I have windows 10 Enterprise 1909, so it's supposed to work. The script in the link just raises the same popup window than https://superuser.com/questions/957907/unable-to-install-fonts-on-windows-10
. Manually copying the font to my AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts folder is possible, but the fonts are not loaded in any application

Comment: It works for me.  What is the application?

Comment: The application I want to use is MS Publisher. But it does not work with WordPad either, nor Outlook. I could not find an application that works

Comment: Even after restarting Windows

Comment: Are the fonts online somewhere?

Comment: These are free fonts I found online, on fontsquirel.com for instance. But I downloaded them and they are on my hard drive. By the way, in your answer, the two first lines of the script are missing.

Comment: Ok I added the two lines.  Which fonts from fontsquirrel?

Comment: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/zilla-slab for instance. Or Bebas, bebas neue. All worked on Windows 7

Comment: It's really the line $Destination.CopyHere($Font) that causes problem. That's why I though about using AddFontRessource instead. But it does not work and I have no error whatsoever

Comment: The Zilla .otf font worked for me in both the Settings app and Wordpad or Notepad.  I added a little error checking to the code.

Comment: I execute the new script: there still is the pop up "The requested file <font file> is not a valid font file" for each of the files in my font folder. The else is not executed. When I go in $($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\, the folder is empty. I tried manually copying the fonts there. It's allowed, but not recognized in Publisher or Wordpad

Comment: I didn't even unblock the files and it worked.  How are you unzipping it?  I used windows explorer.

Comment: I unzipped them with windows explorer. I really believe the files are not corrupted.

Comment: I really believe the files are not corrupted : they worked on Windows 7. Before migrating, I saved them on a network drive, and copied them back locally on the SSD of the new computer. I also downloaded them again. The probability all my font files are corrupted, even when downloaded again from the web site, is very low. I think the problem comes from the firewall or the security restrictions set up by the admin

Comment: Maybe the antivirus is quarantining the font files?  Does the filehash match?  It probably requires registry changes too.

Comment: The files are not deleted nor moved (which I would expect from the antivirus) and McAfee does not log anything in the logs I have access to regarding those files

Answer (score 1):

You can install fonts on windows using following powershell scripts.

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[array]$pcNames,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[string]$fontFolder
)
$padVal = 20
$pcLabel = "Connecting To".PadRight($padVal," ")
$installLabel = "Installing Font".PadRight($padVal," ")
$errorLabel = "Computer Unavailable".PadRight($padVal," ")
$openType = "(Open Type)"
$regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
if(!(Test-Path $fontFolder))
{
    Write-Warning "$fontFolder - Not Found"
}
else
{
    $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($fontFolder)
    foreach ($pcName in $pcNames)
    {
        Try{
            Write-Output "$pcLabel : $pcName"
            $null = Test-Connection $pcName -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
            $destination = "\\",$pcname,"\c$\Windows\Fonts" -join ""
            foreach ($file in $objFolder.items())
            {
                $fileType = $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($file, 2))
                if(($fileType -eq "OpenType font file") -or ($fileType -eq "TrueType font file"))
                {
                    $fontName = $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 21))
                    $regKeyName = $fontName,$openType -join " "
                    $regKeyValue = $file.Name
                    Write-Output "$installLabel : $regKeyValue"
                    Copy-Item $file.Path  $destination
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -ScriptBlock { $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $args[0] -Name $args[1] -Value $args[2] -PropertyType String -Force } -ArgumentList $regPath,$regKeyname,$regKeyValue
                }
            }
        }
        catch{
            Write-Warning "$errorLabel : $pcName"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Using your script tells me :
    Connecting To        : MYCOMPUTERNAME
    Installing Font      : BebasNeue-Regular.otf
    WARNING: Computer Unavailable : MYCOMPUTERNAME. Network discovery is disabled on my computer, maybe this is why? When I type \\MYCOMPUTERNAME in the explorer, it says "this folder is empty"

Comment: I changed the $destination variable to "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\" and it works, but the invoke command then hangs before crashing (computer unavailable)